# AWS - Using Network ACL to restrict outbound traffic to SaaS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We are accessing mailbox on Office 365 from AWS VPC. Is there way to restrict outbound traffic from VPC to only mailbox url? What I Found is using network ACL at subnet level we can restrict outbound traffic by specifying the IP Address range. But I am not sure if we can get IP Address range for office 365 SaaS service. Can some let me know the possibilities of implementing the same?

Comment: NACL and security group work only on IP ranges. If you want to control network traffic based on domains, then you need a custom solution and proxy everything through some firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using VPC prefix lists and security groups.

1. Find the Office 365 URLs and IP ranges [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide) (note: they may be subject to change)
2. Add the IP ranges from 1. to a [customer-managed prefix list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html) in AWS.
3. Create a route entry and/or security group rule that references the prefix list from 2.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. As IP Ranges might vary for office 365 url over a period of time , is there a way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Microsoft provides an RSS endpoint that you can subscribe to and process changes accordingly. The last change date as well as the RSS link can be found near the top of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide

Search for "Change Log subscription"